# How to change the colour of the unfocused edittext hinttext colour in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I need to change the colour of the unfocused `edittext hinttext colour` in `TextinputLayout`. I tried like below. Everything works fine except hint text colour of unfocused `edittext`. What am i doing wrong here?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"          
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme">

        <EditText
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:hint ="Email"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme">

        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/passwordText"
                  android:hint="Password"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#6E6D6D</item>

</style>
```

[image]

Above image is my output, if Email edittext is highlighted means, Password field hinttextcolor should be grey color like password field grey line.

Comment: check this [library](https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/FloatingLabel) it may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is just removing some lines from your code. Remove unnecessary styles from your `styles` and remove `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme"` from your `TextinputLayout`.

Your `style` should be like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Your `XML` should be like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:textColorHint="#404040"    // Change color as per your wish
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:hint ="Email"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="#404040"    // Change color as per your wish
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/passwordText"
                  android:hint="Password"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I have tested it. It will work for you.

Comment: Hi .. it is working fine.. Except that unfocused hint colour is white.. i want that in grey

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>              -- What is the colour value i need to use for ColorPrimary.. here we didn't specify grey anywhere.. how it will consider it?

Comment: see the updated answer. Set hint color in  TextInputLayout that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

try this in your edit text

```
      android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply reverse logic here.Like this:

1. Set all edittext's hint color to grey from layout file.
2. Add onFocusChanged listener to all edittext.
3. Whenever any edittext got focused, change the hint text color of that 
   particular edittext.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

> Remove **android:textColorHint** tag from the style file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easisest way. Just Copy+paste please

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Description">

                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

                            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```